# How to use Rspec to test ApplicationJob executed on callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, callback, jobs

I have a model that executes a Job on a callback:

models/message.rb:

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord

  validates :text, presence: true

  after_create_commit { MessageBroadcastJob.perform_later self }

end
```

The jobs/message_broadcast_job.rb is bellow and it basically render a new message on the screen after it is persisted on database:

```
class MessageBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'room_channel', message: render_message(message)
  end

  private
    def render_message(message)
      ApplicationController.renderer.render(
        partial: 'messages/message',
        locals: { message: message }
      )
    end
end
```

When I created it, Rails also created a spec/jobs/message_broadcast_job_spec.rb for testing. How do I test the Job in this file and how do I test if my Message model (spec/models/message_spec.rb) is calling the job correctly on callback?

Answer (score 0):

You can test if `Message` is calling `MessageBroadcastJob` using `class_stub`.

Try to do something like this in your test:

```
message_broadcast_job_class = class_double("MessageBroadcastJob").as_stubbed_const
expect(message_broadcast_job_class).to receive(:perform_later).with(message)
```